# How to assign to a list of decimal and to a list of string from a list property object and compare decimal

Tags: c#, .net, list, c#-4.0, decimal

How to assign to a list of decimal and also a list of string from a input I get as a list. Some sample code  below. Also, once Assigned decimal list I also need to compare it and if it equals, then do something.

```
public partial class Person
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string ID { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public decimal Amount{ get; set; }
}


public class Details
{
 public List<Person> PersonList { get; set; }
}

List<decimal> Amount = Details.PersonList.Amount;
List<string> ID = Details.PersonList.ID;

if(Amount == decimal.Parse($100, NumberStyles.Currency))
 // do something
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Linq:

```
List<decimal> amounts = details.PersonList.Select(x => x.Amount).ToList();
List<string> ids = details.PersonList.Select(x => x.ID).ToList();
```

---

You do not need `Parse` to specify an amount at compile-time:

```
if (someAmount == 100m)
{
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Jeppe, thank you, but I get the $100 etc from DB, it could be any amount. And IT IS A STRING and contains any value like $100 etc, so I am doing that which gives me 100 or so proper decimal

Comment: @Learner dont store numeric fields in the database as string, it doesn't make any sense

Comment: @Learner I could not see that from your question. I agree with TheGeneral. Be sure you do not compare a _list_ of amounts to just one amount, with `==`, because it is meaningless and disallowed.

Comment: @The General lol I dont want to, but its business requirement :) I am a program manager by innate abilities but I am asked to code :(

Comment: Jeppa, ah I see, but apparently I have a foreach loop to just get one row from DB of which one of the column is this decimal parsed value of a string column :)

Comment: General, the reason is, that column might have any value for different rows. Its sort of business rules.

Comment: @mjwills: As I said, Business wants to store different types of values as a business rule in that column, So not one datatype. it has list, string, decimal, number blah blah...its a static table

Comment: Jeppa, pls help me on how to compare two lists of decimals and if common item found, do something. I can say, I use string.intersect to do for list of string. I dont know whatts for decimal. Also, or can I use foreach decimal value in the list, do compare? Can u pls paste me some simple and easy to understand code, that doesn't throw null or any exception :0